# AS3 changing H/S/B/C of a color

Tags: actionscript-3, colors, brightness, contrast

i'm trying to create a simple drawing app that allows the user to change the Hue, Saturation, Brightness, and Contrast of their color using sliders. I have been looking around and this is all i've came up with, and I need some help to determine why it's not working.

```
var colourFilter:AdjustColor = new AdjustColor();
var mColourMatrix:ColorMatrixFilter;
var mMatrix:Array;

brightSL.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE,changecol) // brightSL would be the brightness slider
contSL.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE,changecol)
satSL.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE,changecol)
hueSL.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE,changecol)


function changecol (SliderEvent):void {
colourFilter.brightness = brightSL.value;
colourFilter.contrast = contSL.value;
colourFilter.saturation = satSL.value;
colourFilter.hue = hueSL.value;

mMatrix = colourFilter.CalculateFinalFlatArray();
mColourMatrix= new ColorMatrixFilter(mMatrix);

selectedColor.filters = [mColourMatrix]; // selectedColor is the color the user is currently using
    board.graphics.lineStyle(sizeSlider.value, selectedColor, alphaSlider.value)
  }
```

The problem is the color doesn't change, and I don't know why.Any help would be appreciated

Comment: After all of the sliders have been moved at least once do you see any changes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not *absolutely* positive, but I believe the problem is that you aren't ensuring that all of the properties on the AdjustColor object are set after the instance is created. Try changing

```
var colourFilter:AdjustColor = new AdjustColor();
var mColourMatrix:ColorMatrixFilter;
var mMatrix:Array;
```

to

```
var colourFilter:AdjustColor = new AdjustColor();
colourFilter.brightness = 0;
colourFilter.contrast = 0;
colourFilter.saturation = 0;
colourFilter.hue = 0;
var mColourMatrix:ColorMatrixFilter;
var mMatrix:Array;
```

If that works but doesn't fit your use case, using `AdjustColor.AllValuesAreSet()` might help.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply ive beena  bit busy, I got two errors with your code when I tried to run it. "1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: AdjustColor." and "1180: Call to a possibly undefined method AdjustColor."

Comment: Sounds like you need an import, too: "import fl.motion.AdjustColor;"

Comment: Ah well that fixed the error but no it didn't change anything, the sliders still don't work :/

Comment: Odd. Does a trace on colourFilter.AllValuesAreSet() return true? What kind of object is selectedColor? I'm guessing a little more context would help.

Comment: Is `AdjustColor` for movieclips? If so, that would be why it does not work. I think the problem lies in what i'm applying the filter to. Im applying it to a color and not an image so I think this would not work, however I am not sure. Are there any other methods to change the h/s/b/v of a color?

Comment: How is the color represented in memory? An unsigned integer (uint)?

Comment: If you just need to display the color, maybe you can use a Bitmap or BitmapData object? The filter and color would be very easy to control there using the BitmapData class' applyFilter and fillRect methods, respectively.

Comment: Well this will be a painting application, so the color is just one of the paramaters in the linestyle. For example `graphics.linestyle(Size,Color,Alpha)` I have rgb sliders that work perfectly, and they are used in as a uint. And do you mean drawing on a Bitmap object and changing the color of the object? That would change the color of any and all lines drawn, which is not what I need. Each line needs to have its own color.

Comment: Let me mull this over for a bit - I've done a LOT of work with the drawing API, so I bet I can come up with something.

Comment: Sure thing :) I really appreciate all your help, I'm really new at ActionScript3 it's the first language I've studied.

Comment: Are you trying to use HSBC to put the finishing touches on an image, or is it being applied to the color of the users' paintbrush? If the latter is the case, perhaps converting from hue-saturation-lightness or hue-saturation-value would be more appropriate? I've always considered HSBC as more of an effect than a property of the color. A good resource: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Formal_derivation